# Sound gaps in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am currently learning guitar and I record my lessons with my phone to practice at home.

I am playing the videos under Linux with VLC (3.0.18) however I constantly need to stop and jump back a few seconds to get everything of the finger placements and movements exact.

Now there is this annoying habit in VLC that the sound goes silent for a second or a half when I jumped back, the sound would return but then go silent again and so on until I let the video play for a few seconds undisturbed.

That's really annoying and really not good for practicing with these sound gaps.

Is there something that can be done about this?